# Pandas: how can I count the amount of different values?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with columns: 'nationality', 'age', 'sex','name','surname' and 1000 rows with data. Nationality can be one of these values 'American','Canadian', 'Chinese', 'Australian'. I need to build a two horizontal bars where on x-axis I would have the nationality('american' or 'canadian' or etc) and on y-axis the number of people of each nationality. The only difference is that in the first bar chart the 'sex' == female, in the second male.
After that mirror the bars.
I assume it can be done by pyplot.barh(), where x is data['nationality'] and the values of y I need to count. How can this can be solved?

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"nationality": ["Canadian","American","American","Chinese","Australian"],
"age": [12,24,20,12,11],
"sex": ['Male','Male','Female','Female','Male'],
"surname": ["Smith","Taylor","Smith","Jones","Norman"]
})
```

Comment: `df['Nationality'].value_counts().plot.bar()`?

Comment: @BigBen Yes, thank you? but is there a way to flip the bar to the left or right?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to create horizontal barplots for male and female would be to use `hue` in a seaborn `countplot`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'nationality': np.random.choice(['American', 'Canadian', 'Chinese', 'Australian'], 1000),
                   'sex': np.random.choice(['male', 'female'], 1000)})
sns.countplot(data=df, y='nationality', hue='sex')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn countplot]

Another option could be to draw the bar plots in two different subplots. Note that the order of the bars need to be set explicitly in both subplots to make sure they are the same.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

countries = ['American', 'Canadian', 'Chinese', 'Australian']
df = pd.DataFrame({'nationality': np.random.choice(countries, 1000, p=[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3]),
                   'sex': np.random.choice(['male', 'female'], 1000)})
sns.countplot(data=df, y='nationality', hue='sex')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 5), sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.3})

sns.countplot(data=df[df['sex'] == 'male'], y='nationality', palette=['navy'], order=countries, ax=ax1)
sns.countplot(data=df[df['sex'] == 'female'], y='nationality', palette=['fuchsia'], order=countries, ax=ax2)
ax1.invert_xaxis()
ax1.set_ylabel('')
ax2.set_ylabel('')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelleft=False)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelleft=True, pad=30) # pad is needed to shift the labels when centered
ax2.set_yticklabels(labels=countries, ha='center')
ax1.set_title('male')
ax2.set_title('female')
plt.show()
```

[image: two barh plots]